# NodeJS Custom Module is Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I'm new to NodeJS (started learning it two weeks ago) and I decided to delve into the realm of creating my own modules. I looked up some articles and found the best way to create a module with a constructor was the following:

```
var Foo = function (params) {
    //Do constructor stuff
    this.params = params;
};

Foo.prototype.test = function () {
    console.log(this.params.Message);
};

module.exports = Foo;
```

Then I would be able do `var myFoo = require("./utils/Foo.js")( { Message: "Some Message });`
This runs the constructor. However, when I do `myFoo.test()` I get an error saying `Cannot read property 'test' of undefined`.

I don't understand why I'm getting the above error. When I add a `console.log("Test")` to the constructor, I see the log.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **this** is not always belongs to Object itself, it can be globals/window object, depends on where you call it.

Comment: Methods of the prototype i believe are only accessible when used with the `new` keyword. See Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/84ssgare/

Comment: @ste2425 Ah. So I can do `module.exports = function (params)return new Foo(params);};`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods of the prototype require the use of the `new` keyword. However when you require it your not using the new keyword.

You have a couple of options. Either put the `new` keyword in when you require it. (Ive split the two apart by the way as im not entirely sure what will happen with the `new` keyword if it was `new require('module')()`. I think it would apply to the require call, not the function call after).

```
var fooModule = require('./foo.js'),
    myFoo = new fooModule('myMessage');
```

Or you could put that logic in your constructor so it will return a new version if the new keyword is omitted; Your require call would not change but your constructor could be something like:

```
var Foo = function (params) {
    if (!(this instanceof Foo)) {
        return new Foo(params);
    }
    //Do constructor stuff
    this.params = params;
};
```

See fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/84ssgare/1/

Generally i would avoid the use of new Keyword anyhow. Its trying to make JavaScript something its not. This [article](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword) List some good examples of exactly how the `new` keyword works. It also makes the good point that its a tool and should be used when required, not because its familiar.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the examples. I've decided to adopt the second implementation as it makes the code look that little bit nicer :P

Answer (score 0):

You need new to create the object from the constructor:

```
var foo=require("./utils/Foo.js");
var myFoo = new foo( { Message: "Some Message });
```

short version:

```
var myFoo = new require("./utils/Foo.js")( { Message: "Some Message });
```

In your actual code you are executing a foo function that reruns undefined. And then trying to access undefined as an object with a test property